# jquery mobile error: object has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a listview click event: http://jsfiddle.net/w2JZU/260/

```
$('#todayvalue').children('li').on('click', function () {
    var selected_index = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
});​
```

This method works well on jquery mobile. But when I deploy it onto PhoneGap javascript files, this error would show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#todayvalue').children('li').click(function () {
var selected_index = $(this).attr('id');
alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
});​
```

.on might not be available on your version of jQuery mobile.

Comment: Newer versions of jQuery have [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as a replacement for `bind`, `live`, and `delegate`.

Comment: 'On' is perfectly acceptable.  In fact, it is provides additional functionality than .click.  It depends on what the OP is trying to do... this may work for them.

Comment: this event won't fire on Phonegap. It works fine for jquerymobile.

Comment: Using click() instead of on('click',...) fixed it for me ; I'm using Phonegap/Cordova and Jquery Mobile. Thanks @sjobe .

Comment: Using bind() instead of on() is also an alternative (see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10912370/189687 )

Answer (score 6):

`on` was introduced to JQuery in v1.7, Nov 2011. It is not yet in JQuery Mobile.

Comment: It is if you are using 1.1-rc-x with jq 1.7.1