# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind

Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

When I use the latest (or a newish) version of jQuery, the small script below works fine. However, when I use older versions of jQuery, my script says that the `on` function does not exist.

Here is my script that doesn't work with older versions of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".theImage").on("click", function(){
        // In the event clicked, find image, fade slowly to .01 opacity
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo("slow", .01).end()
        // Then, of siblings, find all images and fade slowly to 100% opacity
               .siblings().find("img").fadeTo("slow", 1);           
    })
})
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You must use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), as `on` was only introduced in [jQuery 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".theImage").bind("click", function(){
        // In the event clicked, find image, fade slowly to .01 opacity
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo("slow", .01).end()
        // Then, of siblings, find all images and fade slowly to 100% opacity
        .siblings().find("img").fadeTo("slow", 1);           
    })
})
```

Comment: Woah that was quick man... 12 minutes until I can accept an answer. I'll check it as correct... works great!

Comment: @Christoph the user is asking why his code (with `.on()`)is not working with older version of jQuery... so this answer is fine

Comment: But bind doesn't have the same behaviour as .on, which is why the op presumably used .on rather than .click? .live is the alternative

Comment: @Alex - In this case, `bind` and `on` function in the same way. No selector is being passed to `on`, which would cause it to delegate the event handler.

Comment: @F.Calderan The answer doesn't address the *why* of it at all, though the question never specifically asks why. It just says "this is the fix", without explaining what the original problem was; I'll let people decide for themselves whether that constitutes a full answer.

Comment: of course everyone chooses for themselves :) to me is fine because it solves the problem - and it was a reply to a deleted comment

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), for example:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

This is equivalent to the following code written using `on()`:

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

Comment: Whilst the equivalences you describe in your answer are correct, `delegate()` is *not* equivalent to the OP's usage of `on()` in the question (he attaches the element directly to the `.theImage`, where as you delegate to another element).

Comment: FYI: as of jQuery 1.7 `delegate()` has been superseded by `on()`

Answer (score 1):

You must use jQuery version 1.7+ to use `on()`. `bind()` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you, don't know why people downvoted this but I placed 1.7 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `on` function to `bind`:

`.children().on("click",function()`
 **to** 
`.children().bind("click",function()`