# Filter/search function not targetting dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, html-table

I found an example of how to search for values in a table.

```
 var $userRows = $('#UserTableContainer tr');
    $('#searchuser').keyup(function () {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $userRows.show().filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\screen+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return ! ~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
```

It works fine on "normal" tables, see for instance this http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/ However, I add values to my table using jQuerys template function.

```
function PrintUsers(item) {
    $.template('userList', '<tr>\
         <td>${Firstname} ${Lastname}</td>\
         </tr>');

    $.tmpl('userList', item).appendTo("#UserTableContainer");
}
```

When I try to search for elements in my table it only filters my header, i.e. the "Name" row in this table.

```
    <table id="UserTableContainer">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update code**
http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/128/
You need to use `'on'` for dom elements that are added dynamic.So we can't use using keyup on present dom .
The way to use is::

```
 $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);
```

Comment: Alright. I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'" when I'm trying to use the updated code. Is there anything I need to include to use it?

Comment: You perhaps  are using  an old version of jQuery. . on works for jquery 1.7+ You can use live or delegate(delegate should be used for jQuery versions other than 1.7.x.) [Read more]here(http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Just noticed that I in fact can see the "on" function in my Intellisense. And yeah, I'm using jQuery 1.8. I keep getting the error though. Do I need to add the function into any specific part of the JavaScript document?

Comment: have u wrapped it in $(document).ready(function () {//code  }); .. Look more in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912346/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-on

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to answer my questions. I've already tried wrapping it in .ready-tags and I also already checked that link. None of them gave me any idea what goes wrong. :/

Comment: would you mind telling what you did wrong in order to let other know ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Tobias, your markup is probably wrong.

Btw if you will be using table headers and you don't want this to filter these:

```
var $rows = $('#table tr').not(':first');
```