# Search filter not working when loading content added dynamically via fetch() or AJAX load()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm using a simple search filter to filter several links that I have.

**The script looks like this:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);
function myFunction(e) {
    var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var list = document.getElementById("links-list");
    var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a) {
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                divs[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The HTML:**

```html
<button id="anchor-open-cards-list-btn">Load</button>
<input id="search-filter-cards">
<div id="links-list">
    // links here
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Sample link:**

```html
<div class="card link-container">
  <img src="assets/links.png"/>
  <a class="link-title" href="#">SAMPLE LINK</a>
</div>
```

This search filter works fine if I don't load the content dynamically. But since there's hundreds of them, I used `fetch()` first, then AJAX `load()` to improve the page's loading speed.

The problem then is, the filter doesn't work anymore when I do so.
I fetch it `onclick` of a button using a simple script..

**fetch()**

```js
function fetchMainMenuQuickLinks() {
    fetch('../components/main-menu-quick-links.html')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => document.querySelector('#component-main-menu-quick-links').innerHTML = text);
}
```

**I also tried AJAX load()**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#anchor-open-cards-list-btn").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("test-content.html");
    });
});
```

These two loads the content sure, but the search filter is no longer working by doing so..

The only alternative I can think of that I can pull is a simple `document.write()`, but I wouldn't prefer that..

How do I fix such an issue? I'm still new in learning JS and I don't know every workaround..

I believe my problem is the same as this: [Filter/search function not targetting dynamically added rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471361/filter-search-function-not-targetting-dynamically-added-rows). But I tried the solution they posted but it didn't work either for my case.

Comment: You're just settings the innerText of your container to the response of the fetch. this'll be seen as a string. You want to parse the text returned from the fetch into a DOM object before appending to the document.

Comment: You are also mixing jQuery and standard selectors. `document.querySelector('#component-main-menu-quick-links').innerHTML = text` could be something like: `$('#component-main-menu-quick-links').append($(text));`

Comment: It sounds like you need event delegation : [event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) but it's essentially the same solution as the one you say didn't work.  Given you've not provided any HTML, it's hard to tell if `#search-filter-cards` is recreated, requiring delegated events.

Comment: @Pellay Can you pls show me how that works?

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry to ask, but can you pls show me how to properly use event delegation? I couldn't make it work.. Also, the html is available above. It works by adding the `sample links` I have above too.

Comment: `#search-filter-cards` is shown, but not how it relates to `#box` or `#component-main-menu-quick-links` which is the part(/parts?) that's recreated (depending which code you're using)

Comment: As tagged *jquery* delegate events would change `var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards"); input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);` to `$(document).on("input", "#search-filter-cards", myFunction);`  (not sure about the `e` parameter, but if you get the event after your load then that's the issue)

Comment: Oh, in that case, the html is a simple `<div id="box"></div>` triggered by a button `<button id="anchor-open-cards-list-btn">Load</button>`. This is for JQuery, and slightly changed for `fetch()`..

Comment: it maybe not about delegate event, the `fetch()`  insert html into `#component-main-menu-quick-links` while the function search `#links-list a`. except the `<button id="anchor-open-cards-list-btn">Load</button>` is dynamically added.