# Cannot get the value of datepicker of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to use datepicker of Jquery, but it seems I cannot catch the selected value of my datepicker.

My added HTML is:

```
test Date:<input type="text" id="testDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
<input type="button" id="testbtn" value="my button"/>
```

in my javascript inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I have the following code:

```
$("#testDate").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
$('#testbtn').click(function() {
    console.log($('#testDate').val());
});
```

but nothing is written in my console! Am I missing something? Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZNrAQ/1/

Comment: Thanks buddy for letting me know! I just figured out that I had the following erro
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'click'
and the following thread solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912346/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-on
Thanks