# Bootstrap 3 carousel not working on Magento

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap

Can't get this carousel to work on a Magento site. I have one image displaying ok, just the transition between images not happening.

Example that im working on here - http://dev.clothesforsale.co.nz/

Code below:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators  -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides  -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);?>slider/example-banner-one.jpg" alt="Slider One" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);?>slider/example-banner-two.jpg" alt="Slider Two" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    $(function(){
       $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the console shows `Object #<Object> has no method 'on'` when the page loads, originating on line 163 of bootstrap.js. If I `jQuery.fn.jquery` in the console to get the jQuery version, it says `1.4.2`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912346/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-on) suggests that the `on` method (which Bootstrap appears to be using) wasn't added until jQuery 1.7. An upgrade might be the first step.